# Mix Javascript template tags with Web2Py template tags

Tags: web2py

Is there a way I can use knockout.js variables that use the same template tag {{ }} as web2py uses for python code in web2py somewhow? In django I can use the verbatim tag to exclude some code from being processed by the template engine or I can change the default django template tags so something else. How I can I do it with Web2PY? 
Thank you!

g

g

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing similar to the Django verbatim tag, but you can set custom delimiters (possibly on a per route basis) via [`response.delimiters`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#The-views):

```
response.delimiters = ['{%', '%}']
```

The above can go in a model file (to apply to all requests), or in a controller action (to apply to a single route).